# How to Inject NavController to an activity using Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I'm new to Hilt. Trying to convert from Dagger to Hilt. But I'm stuck on injecting `NavController` to the `Activity`.

So to create `NavController` instance I need to have access to the activity and the host fragment Id. In Dagger this was my approach to create that instance.

First, create `ActivityModule`

```
@Module
class ActivityModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    fun navigation(activity: MainActivity, hosFragment: Int) =
        Navigation.findNavController(activity,hosFragment)
}
```

In the second step `ActivitySubComponent` has the ability to take activity and host fragment id as parameters.

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules = [ActivityModule::class])
interface ActivitySubComponent {

    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory{
        fun create(@BindsInstance activity: MainActivity,
                   @BindsInstance hostFragment: Int): ActivitySubComponent
    }

    fun inject(MainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

After adding this subcomponent with other subcomponents to the `ApplicationComponent` from you can get the instance of `NavController` to the fragment like below.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var navigationController: NavController
    lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        injector.activityComponent().create(this, R.id.hostFragment).inject(this)

    }
}
```

`injector` coming from the following class.

```
interface InjectorProvider {
  val component: ApplicationComponent
}

val Activity.injector get() = (application as InjectorProvider).component
val Fragment.injector get() = (requireActivity().application as InjectorProvider).component
```

When I was trying to transition into Hilt, the first issue I faced was how to provide parameters to the module. Not like in Dagger I could not find an alternative for Subcomponent Factory. Is it even possible to provide parameters to a module on Hilt?

Anyways, I decided to provide the `FragmentContainerView` id to the `NavController` manually since it's not changing. With that, I came to the below solution in Hilt.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object NavigationModule {

    @Provides
    fun navigationController(activity: Activity) =
        activity.findNavController(R.id.hostFragment)
}
```

And tried to inject it into my `MainActvity` like below.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var navigationController: NavController
    lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        initialization()

    }

    private fun initialization() {

        setSupportActionBar(viewBinding.toolbar)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navigationController)

    }

}
```

Application built successfully but now I'm getting a run time error saying "ID does not reference a View inside this Activity" but my activity layout is constructed like below.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple_700"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/hostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Error pointing at `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` line on the `MainActivity`. Please let me know what am I missing here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. The above issue must be caused by the fact the UI is not available at the time it tries to inject the `NavController` instance. So Hilt has a way of defining an interface and Injecting that interface into the Activity. And we can define the classes by that implementing that interface. This gives us a chance to provide the parameters necessary to build our instance when they are available.

First, create the interface like below.

```
interface AppNavigator {
    
    fun getNaveHostFragment(hostFragmentId: Int): NavController
    
}
```

Secondly, create an implementation class.

```
class AppNavigatorImplementation @Inject constructor(private val activity: FragmentActivity): AppNavigator {

    override fun getNaveHostFragment(hostFragmentId: Int): NavController {
        val navHostFragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.hostFragment) as NavHostFragment
        return navHostFragment.navController
    }

}
```

After that define `NavigationModule` like below.

```
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class NavigationModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindNavigator(impl: AppNavigatorImplementation): AppNavigator

}
```

Finally, you can inject that instance to the activity like below.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var navigator: AppNavigator
    lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navigationController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        initialization()

    }

    private fun initialization() {

        navigationController = navigator.getNaveHostFragment(R.id.hostFragment)

        setSupportActionBar(viewBinding.toolbar)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navigationController)

    }
}
```